# Meaning of Recuseniks

Tags: meaning

> The **Recuseniks** Come for the Trump Case Judge ... Democratic and media **recuseniks** always do this.

They are the title and the part of [the Wall Street Journal opinion](https://www.wsj.com/articles/judge-aileen-cannon-donald-trump-classified-documents-mar-a-lago-indictment-451b76ea?st=el1gk7fd1dwgjet&reflink=desktopwebshare_permalink).

What do R(r)ecuseniks mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The suffix *-nik* is Yiddish in origin, and is sometimes added to words to turn them into a '*nickname*' for somebody or a group of people. This is more common in US English, and particularly in US states with a strong influence from Jewish culture. I note that your quote comes from the New-York-City-based newspaper *The Wall Street Journal*.

The verb 'recuse' means "*to disqualify or seek to disqualify (a judge or juror) from participation in the decision in a case, as for personal prejudice against a party or for personal interest in the outcome*". So, a *recusenik* would be someone who desires that outcome, which fits the context of your quotation.

Although you won't find the word in dictionaries, English is extremely flexible in allowing for the creation of 'new' compound words either by using familiar prefixes and suffixes or by making a recognisable portmanteau. Not every native English speaker would instantly know what 'recusenik' meant, but the suffix is recognisable enough to make us reach for the dictionary and look up 'recuse'.

This particular word may also be an intentional **pun** on the word *re**f**usenik*, which can mean someone who refuses to do something or was refused something. This word is found in dictionaries and has a significant meaning in Jewish history as it can refer to Soviet Jews who were refused immigration rights in the 1970s.

Comment: The  -nik ending is found in Russian, too. Refuseniks were people denied permission to emigrate from the Soviet Union. Russian отказник (romanized as otkaznik) from отказ (otkaz) 'refusal'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey True... as in *Sputnik*. But I'm certain that the use in New York culture comes from Jewish influence rather than Russian. I don't want to add in to my answer that it has some use in Slavic languages because I think that would detract from the fact this is about its use in English.

Comment: Yes, NY Jewish, as in e.g. 'I don't want my daughter to marry a no-goodnik'.

Comment: Historical evidence suggests that widespread usage in American English was borrowed originally from Russian and started when Sputnik 1 made the news in 1957 (prior to that, any usage in English at all is essentially nonexistent, after that there is a nontrivial amount of usage found even if you ignore the special case of ‘Sputnik’). Modern usage is definitely influenced by Yiddish usage of the same suffix though (also borrowed from Slavic languages there, though possibly not from Russian specifically), but the Slavic connection is still significant.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Interesting if true. What I am certain about is that the modern evidence shows the usage is almost entirely in US Jewish cultures and those influenced by it. So even if it did come from Russian, it came via Jewish communities and was assimilated into Yiddish before it crossed over into English. And that would have taken some time - it wouldn't have immediately happened after 1957. Did you know that those 'Troll' dolls from the late 1950s were called 'Wishniks' in some territories? I'd love to see this historical evidence you mentioned.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Just did some cursory research - apparently '*raskolnik*' has been in the Oxford English dictionary since 1723. Also, American comic artist Al Capp frequently used the suffix to create nicknames in his 1934 comic. Capp was of Eastern-European Jewish heritage. This was noted in a late edition of *The American Language*. Again, I'd love to see this historical evidence you mentioned.

Comment: All of this is true, but a key ingredient lacking here is the (in my mind clear and obvious) time-honored tradition of linking of Democrats with communism. It is fine to quote old sources, but there is a massive upsurge in this currently especially, see *vatnick*. I mention this mainly to give some sense for the OP of the cultural implication.

Comment: I think this answer (while correct) would be improved with a one-line summary of what it means: "A group of people that zealously [in the author's opinion] want all Trump-appointed judges to recuse themselves in any cases dealing with Trump." The point is the author of the opinion (*WSJ* is famously conservative) thinks Democrats are being over-the-top in wanting judicial recusals.